# File upload using react using react-hook-form & react-step-builder

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to submit a form using react-hook-form & react-step-builder in react js, I managed to submit the form without file all other fields are working except the file.

How can I achieve this:

```
<input
    {...register("idproof", { required: true })}
    onChange={props.handleChange}
    style={styles.file}
    type="file"
/>
```

My code is also giving an error when I tried to put it in codesandbox so I can't give a working example but I will put the link to codesandbox here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-worker-zicnr?file=/src/App.js